# CommonName doesn't match with Server Name (SSL on Amazon EC2)

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm facing difficulty when I am trying to upload an self signed certificate on Amazon EC2 instance. I have generated my private key and also server certificate using OpenSSL. But when I configure it in .config file of apache and restart the server, it says "RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx' does NOT match server name!?" CommonName given during generation of crt was www.mydomain.com.

Where do I change the CommonName (ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx) on EC2? Below is my .config content.(YAML Syntax Validated)

```html
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

packages:
  yum:
    mod_ssl : []
    
files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ServerName            www.mydomain.com
        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
        
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        
        LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
        TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
      </VirtualHost>
      
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----<my crt content>-----END CERTIFICATE-----
      
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----<my private key content>-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

container_commands:
  killhttpd:
    command: "killall httpd"
  waitforhttpddeath:
    command: "sleep 3"
```

Thanks.

Comment: If your website is secured by a certificate with the name www.example.com you will receive this error if you connect using any of the following names:
example.com
example.local
208.77.188.166
10.1.1.7 - In this case I believe you have to remake your certificate. Use a multi-domain certificate or a wildcard domain (be careful with this) to solve this.

Comment: With wildcard domain certificate, the issue still exists.

Comment: Your certificate is self-signed or you have purchased from a certificate authority?

Answer (score 0):

You said "CommonName given during generation of crt was www.mydomain.com" but this isn't a wildcard certifcate.

A wildcard must be something like this *.yourdomain.com, this way you can use this certificate in any machine under the yourdomain.

See in this link how to do that.
[Generate wildcard self-signed certificate for apache](http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/how-to-create-self-signed-wildcard-ssl-certificates-for-apache/)

Comment: I did regenerate the certificate with wildcard domain and tested it, and issue still exists.